# Concurrent web request performance issues

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library

I am working on a new service to run QA for our companies' multiple web properties, and have run into an interesting network concurrency issue.  To increase performance, I am using the TPL to create HttpWebRequests based from a large collection of urls so that they can run in parallel; however, I can't seem to find where the bottleneck is in the process.

My observations so far:

- I can get a max of about 25-30 parallel threads via the TPL
- The CPU never breaks 5-6% for the service (running on 1 - 4 cores, with and without H/T)
- NIC usage never breaks 2-3%
- Overall network traffic doesn't seem to be affected (other users don't complain, speed tests run at the same time don't show much of an affect)
- Speed does not change much between running on our office network (15Mbps) or our data center (100+Mbps)
- I get a bit of a performance gain by downloading from multiple hosts at once rather than a lot of pages from one host.

Possible pain points:

- CPU (number of cores or hardware threads)
- NIC
- Max allowed number of concurrent HttpWebRequests
- LAN
- WAN
- Router/Switch/Load balancer

**So the question is:**

Obviously there is now way to download the entire internet in a matter of minutes, but I am interested to know where the bottleneck is in a scenario like this and what, if anything, can be done to overcome it.

As a side note, we are currently using a 3rd party service for crawling, but we are limited by them in some ways and would like more flexibility.  Something about corporate secret sauce or [poison on the tip of the arrow](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/15/user-experience-and-the-poison-on-the-tip-of-the-arrow/) ... :)

Comment: Can you post a few details about your code? I'm running a crawler with 100 parallel threads with no issues. I'm on .NET 4 and the server is nothing much. I'm using NCrawler in the backend.

Comment: The code is really very simple. I use Parallel.ForEach to loop through a collection of URLs (strings).  The action creates an HttpWebRequest and then dumps the results into a ConcurrentBag.  BTW, NCrawler seems interesting; I'll check it out.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's a limit on the number of concurrent HttpWebRequest's to the same host IIRC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suspect one of the following is the cause:

1. You are running into the default connection limit. Check the value of ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit. I recommend you set it to a practically infinite value such as 1000.
2. The TPL is not starting as many threads as are necessary to saturate the network. Notice, that remote web servers can have a large amount of latency. While waiting, your thread is not putting load on the network.

The TPL does not guarantee you any minimum degree of parallelism (DOP). That is a pity because sometimes you really need to control the degree of parallelism exactly when working with IO.

I recommend you manually start a fixed number of threads to do your IO because that is the only way to guarantee a specific DOP. You need to experiment with the exact value. It could be in the range of 50 to 500. You can reduce the default stack size of your threads to save memory with that many threads.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What I like about the TPL, though, is that it easily allows a single build to work on a wide variety of machines without having to write a lot of code to manage the number hardware threads.

Comment: @SteveKonves this is true but it only applies to CPU-bound work. Your code sounds like it should be network bound. The TPL will actively get into your way and mismanage resources.

Comment: usr's first point is almost certainly the case. Regardless of how you manage you're threads, you're going to have to watch out for the DefaultConnectionLimit.

Comment: You can effectively set a minimum DOP by calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()`. And if you wanted to use a specific DOP, you could use a custom `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: @svick, I like the idea of a custom task scheduler. Not sure if MinThreads is used for TPL stuff. Also, it is a process-global setting.

Comment: @usr MinThreads is used in TPL, as long as your `Task`s run on the `ThreadPool`, which by default they do. You can change that by using a custom `TaskScheduler` or specifying the `LongRunning` option.

Comment: @svick, ok you're right. But the TPL might not only undersaturate the network but also oversubscribe. It is prone to spawn threads indefinitely until the limit is reached. The only solution that I consider acceptable is a somehow exactly controlled number of threads. LongRunning might well be useful for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're hitting TCP connections limit, or not disposing of connections properly, in any case try using something like JMeter to see the max concurrent HTTP throughput you can get.

Answer (score 1):

> The code is really very simple. I use Parallel.ForEach to loop through
>   a collection of URLs (strings). The action creates an HttpWebRequest
>   and then dumps the results into a ConcurrentBag. BTW, NCrawler seems
>   interesting; I'll check it out. Thanks for the tip.

Because with Parallel.ForEach is impossible to control the number of threads,then I suggest at least switching to a `ThreadPool`.

You can use [`QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) to allocate work until  your task collection is completely pushed to worker threads or until the method returns false (no more threads in pool).

With `ThreadPool` you can control the maximum number of threads to be allocated with [`SetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx).

Comment: Why would you suggest using `ThreadPool` directly if you can use `Task`s? They are much more convenient. And I don't think the maximum number of threads in the thread pool is a problem here, it's usually large enough.